# Set visibility of form input in thymleaf using th:if

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, url-routing, thymeleaf

I am new to thymeleaf and I have this problem. 
I have a form to add and edit products.
From the controller I set request mapping to access this form view using

```
@RequestMapping("/products/add")
```

and

```
@RequestMapping("/products/edit/{id}")
```

I have a field in products ,Date endPromotion. 
I want this input block that has endPromotion field to be shown only in edit mode. 
How can I do that using thymleaf condition?

i tried somthing like

```
<div th:if="${|/products/{action}(action='edit')|}"> .. valid html code ... </div>
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: can you please add more description?

Comment: @ravi-kavaiya - I want to include in the form something like this <div th:if="${|/products/{action}(action='edit'|)"> .. valid html code ... </div>

Comment: you means you need configure you form based on URL?

Comment: i think you are looking like this  
*<div
        th:if="${(param.action != null) and (param.action[0] == 'edit')}">
           html code
 </div>*

Comment: Thanks alot . This is the solution

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
<div th:if="${#strings.contains(#httpServletRequest.requestURI, '/products/edit/')}">
some content
</div>
```